# remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/

Tags: flutter, git, github, github-actions, desktop

'''
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/e_officeVisit1': reference already exists

! [remote rejected] e_officeVisit1 -> e_officeVisit1 (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to
'''

am getting this error while trying to push or publish the branch

i tried
$ git ls-remote

on $ git branch --unset-upstream
it throws
'''
fatal: Branch 'e_officeVisit1' has no upstream information
'''

and also
$git remote prune origin

none of this are working, any solutions???